# STS : Using JSF , Managed beans and Aspects

Tags: spring, jsf, aop

Main idea is to use JSF with Spring AOP for modularizing cross cutting concerns like logging.
I am using STS (Spring tool suite) and have jsp page with jsf tags. These tags are reading data from a managed bean properties(getter). I have aspect configured for the getters. When i run application with Java/AspectJ getter is called and aspect advice code is executed and it prints out using system.out.println a message to console.
But when i load jsf page there is no output on the console. 
Any idea how can i integrate these aspects with calls from JSF or JSP pages ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
<el-resolver>
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
```

and the managed beans are part of the spring-context (either via the `@Controller` annotation, or in `applicationContext.xml`), the aspects should work with them.